# Pointer set to null

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
class GlobalClass
{

    static GlobalClass *s_instance;

  public:
    static GlobalClass *instance()
    {
        if (!s_instance)
          s_instance = new GlobalClass;
        return s_instance;
    }
    void SetPointer(void *ptr)
    {
        this->PointerSetter(ptr);
        std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr << std::endl;
    }
    void PointerSetter(void *ptr)
    {
        int Value = 1;
        ptr = &Value; 
        std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr << std::endl;
    }
};

GlobalClass *GlobalClass::s_instance = 0;

int main()
{
   void *ptr=NULL;
   std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr << std::endl;
   GlobalClass::instance()->SetPointer(ptr);
   std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ptr:0
ptr:0x6ffddc
ptr:0
ptr:0
```

I am not able to understand why the pointer that I passed to function `SetPointer` in the singleton instance of `GlobalClass` which in turn is passed to `PointerSetter` is not visible when it comes out of `PointerSetter`. I need to access it in my `main` function. 
How is the pointer is being set to NULL or 0?

Comment: You're passing `ptr` by value to `PointerSetter` so even if you change the address it's pointing to, you're only changing it for the `PointerSetter` `ptr`. Pass your pointers by reference to solve this (or add another level of indirection)

Comment: Note that the only reason this situation is confusing is because you've named three completely different variables the same thing and therefore expect them to be the same.

Comment: Thank you. Got it!

Comment: Also, using a local variable after returning from the function would be undefined behavior... if you try to dereference the variable.